# Screen reader aria live assertive text is interrupted

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

```js
$('#firstButton').focus();
```

```html
<div id="liveRegion" aria-live="assertive">
  This is a very long text
</div>
<button id="firstButton">First Button</button>
```

I am quite a newbie in accessibility issues. I basically have a button on which I want the focus to be on page load, but I also want a text to be picked up by the screenreaders in the liveRegion.
Right now, the text will be inteerrupted at some point during page load, and focus goes to the button.
Is there a way to have the screenreader not be interrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Live regions can be confusing at first.  The purpose of a live region is to announce **changes** to the page, not to announce page load information.  After your page is loaded, if something changes on the page, such as the text within an element, or a new element is added, those changes can be announced if the `aria-live` attribute is used.

Most pages do not announce anything as they're loaded.  A screen reader user will hear that the page is loading, and when it's done (usually there's an audible clue in the screen reader to let you know if the page is still loading or if it's done), the page title is typically announced and then whatever object has initial focus is read.

If you really need something read after the page loads, then it should probably have the initial focus.  But be careful because putting focus on a non-interactive element such as a paragraph (`<p>`) or non-semantic elment (`<div>`) can be confusing.  If you have to resort to that, make sure that element has `tabindex="-1"` so that the element will not be in normal keyboard focus order.

Answer (score 0):

as such, there is no way to prevent the reading of your text by the button gaining focus.
The order of priority of what to say when heavily depends on screen reader / browser / OS combination, but usually, an element taking the focus has priority against any live region, including assertive.

What you can do is making the live region assertive text appear after the focus is moved to the button.
It has greater chances to be announced without interruption then.

IN any case, a live region present at page load isn't reliably read on all platforms.
To make sure that it will be effectively spoken, make it appear in the DOM after the page has completely finished to load.